# Calling controller from twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm currently discovering Symfony, and I have some trouble calling a function from one of my controllers.

```
> class CsvController extends Controller {

public function generateCsvAction(){
    $conn=$this->get('database_connection')

    $results=$conn->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM external_attribute;
    ")

    $response=new StreamedResponse();
    $response->setCallback(function() use($results)){
        $handle=fopen("/home/basile/Documents/backend/src/CampaignBundle/Controller/test.csv","w+");
        fputcsv($handle,array('test1
            test2,
            test3,
            test4,
            test5,
            test6,
            test7,
            test8')
        ),';');
    }

    fclose($handle);
}

$response->setStatusCode(200);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=utf-8');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="test.csv"');      
return $response;
```

}

I already set everything in my routing.yml :

```
export_csv:
defaults: { _controller: CampaignBundle:Controller:CsvController.php }
```

and now I want to call it from a button in a file named "index.html.twig" . I know we can render from the controller some variables and array, but here i directly want to  call a function

If you have any kind of idea, it would be very welcomed !

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the view `index.html.twig` ?

Comment: Why don't you just use Twig `path()` function?

Answer (score 7):

To directly call a controller from your template :

```
{{ render(controller(
    'NameOfYourBundle:NameOfYourClass:NameOfYourFunction'
)) }}
```

If controller needs parameters (eg) :

```
{{ render(controller(
    'NameOfYourBundle:NameOfYourClass:NameOfYourFunction', { 'id': 3 }
)) }}
```

Comment: Thank you, but can I call it from a JS onclick() function ?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you really want to do. If you want to call a controller with an onclick, maybe you just have to location.href to the desired route ? Or maybe you want to make something dynamic inside the same page with this button. In this case, you have to use ajax

Comment: Well that's what i'm trying to do : I have a webpage with some buttons on it. I want to call the function GenerateCsvAction() when i'm click on it !

Comment: if I were you this is what i did : <button onclick="pathOfYourControllerRoute">Generate csv</button>

Answer (score 0):

you can execute the function directly from your view:

```
{% render "YourBundle:Csv:generateCsv" with { 'url': 'export_csv' } %}
```

By JS and AJAX :

```
$("#button").on('click', function() { 
 $.ajax({
    url: {{render(controller("YourBundle:Csv:generateCsv")) }},
    success: function(result){
    ...
 }});

});
```

Comment: Yes i could do that, but I want to call it from an onClick() function ! I don't realy know if i can call some TWIG in a JS function